# Python stdout logging: terminal vs bash file

Tags: python, linux, bash, terminal, stdout

I am not expert in Bash and Python, so this question might appear silly.

I have a Python script called `learn.py` and I noticed two different behaviours of the standard output, when redirected to a log file.

If I call this from terminal, I can see the log file size growing while the script is running.

```
$ ./learn.py > file.log
```

However, if I create a bash file for the same purpose:

```
#!/bin/bash
./learn.py > file.log
```

the script starts (I checked with `pgrep`) but it does not seem to run, as the log file stays empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you post what your `learn.py` script does?

Comment: even if all you put in `learn.py` is `print "Hello?"` ...

Comment: @Balthamos `learn.py` is a complex script which uses NLTK libraries. @JoranBeasley It works putting just "hello". Is it possible that the file will be filled only at the end of the computation?

Comment: It's buffering, but I don't know why it would decide to buffer only in the script. How did you start it?

Comment: @thatotherguy I start the bash script with `./launcher` after setting it executable with `chmod +x`.

Comment: @mommi84 Weird. Standard programs will use the same buffering strategy in those cases. The file should fill up in chunks though, if you just let it run for a while.

Comment: I have been running it for almost 1 hour now, it should have finished long ago. One CPU is still at 100%, though. I think I will give up and try Python's logging facility. Thanks anyway!

Comment: How are you running the shell script? Can you run `strace` on the `learn.py` process to see what it is doing when run by the script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved using the [Logging facility for Python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html), by inserting

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='file.log',level=logging.INFO)
```

and replacing every occurrence of `print "..."` with

```
logging.info("...")
```

The final Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./learn.py
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nohup`:

Also you can use & to make it run in the background

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup python learn.py >> file.log &
```